# Hibernate + Oracle Group By Results in ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error

Tags: oracle, hibernate, group-by

I have the following Hibernate HQL query:

```
select t from Term t join ApprovedCourse ap on t.id = ap.term.id group by t order by t desc
```

It's failing with the

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

error because Oracle insists that all select values be in the group by.  Hibernate, of course, is hiding the various fields of the Term object from us, letting us deal with it as a Term and not Term.id.  (This query works on Postgres, by the way.  Postgres is more liberal about its group by requirements.)

Hibernate is producing the following SQL:

```
select term0_.id as id1_12_, term0_.semester_id as semester_id2_12_, term0_.year_id as year_id3_12_ 
  from term term0_ 
 inner join approved_course approvedco1_ 
    on (term0_.id=approvedco1_.term_id) 
 group by term0_.id 
 order by term0_.id desc
```

I've tried just removing the `select t` from the start of the query, but then Hibernate assumes that I'm selecting both the Term and ApprovedCourse objects, and that makes things worse.

So how do I make this work in a Hibernate way?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could get what I want by replacing the group by clause with a distinct in the select clause.  Here's the resulting query:

```
select distinct(t) from Term t join ApprovedCourse ap on t.id = ap.term.id  order by t desc
```